# Choosing Column name based on variable name to update value

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a piece of code to update a column value but it gives me error:

```
UPDATE #Cal SET @Curr = @2YD where Day = 'D-3WD'
```

I tried `EXEC` command using:

```
SELECT @sql = "UPDATE #Cal SET " + @Cur + " = " + @2YD + "where Day = 'D-2WD'"
EXEC @sql
```

but I get following error:

> Syntax error during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value 'where Day = 'D-2WD'' to a DATE field.

Why is it trying to convert the value to date field?

Comment: So does the error occur when you execute the statement explicitly, or only when the statement is created dynamically?

Comment: It occurs while compiling, does not go to EXEC

Comment: `SELECT @sql = "UPDATE #Cal SET " + @Cur + " = " + @2YD + " where Day = 'D-2WD'"
EXEC @sql`

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert explicitly:

```
SELECT @sql = "UPDATE #Cal SET " + convert (varchar(25),@Cur) + " = " + convert (varchar(25),@2YD ) + "where Day = 'D-2W
```